# Replacing Default IModuleInitializer Using MEF in Prism

Tags: prism, mef

I'm trying to override the implementation Mefmoduleinitializer on their own, as described in  [Replacing Default Types Using MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430866%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).
My class (in Shells assembly) is :

```
[Export(typeof(IModuleInitializer))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class SafeMefModuleInitializer: MefModuleInitializer
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly ILoggerFacade    _loggerFacade;

    [ImportingConstructor()]
    public SafeMefModuleInitializer(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, ILoggerFacade loggerFacade, DownloadedPartCatalogCollection downloadedPartCatalogs, AggregateCatalog aggregateCatalog, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
    : base(serviceLocator, loggerFacade, downloadedPartCatalogs, aggregateCatalog)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _loggerFacade = loggerFacade;
    }

    public override void HandleModuleInitializationError(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, string assemblyName, Exception exception)
    {
        try {
            base.HandleModuleInitializationError(moduleInfo, assemblyName, exception);
        }
        catch (ModuleInitializeException ex) {
            _loggerFacade.Error(
                string.Format(
                    "Module {0} failed to load and has been disabled.", moduleInfo.ModuleName
                ), 
                ex
            );
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ModuleLoadErrorEvent>().Publish(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And in Bootstrapper:

```
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(
            new DirectoryCatalog(".")
        );
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(
            new DirectoryCatalog(Properties.Settings.Default.ModuleCatalogPath)
        );
    }
```

Runtime I get MEF error:

```
"More than one export was found that matches the constraint: ContractName
Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleInitializer RequiredTypeIdentity
Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleInitializer"
```

How can I correct replace MefModuleInitializer to my SafeMefModuleInitializer in MEF CompositionContainer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the base method after you add the new MefModuleInitializer

```
protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
{
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(
        new DirectoryCatalog(".")
    );
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(
        new DirectoryCatalog(Properties.Settings.Default.ModuleCatalogPath)
    );

    base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
}
```